# How to download the SharePoint 2019 folder or mutiple files once time?

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, spfx, custom-actions

The server has been configured to the public network, so I cannot use the file explorer. And the solution needs to be integrated into SharePoint, so the PowerShell code will not be accepted.

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use OneDrive to sync the library to you local machine and keep a copy there. Also using you can try to use PowerShell to download files in bulk.

Comment: I have tried to use onedrive to synchronize files, but the domain account cannot log in to onedrive.